# lightning:datatable Multi-Level/ Nested

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I'm looking to see to create a multi level lightning data table in LWC.

(ie)
The parent object has a school Information, If selected a sub level(down arrow) opens and you can see the child records with there own actions, held in there own datatable as screenshot below.

As like below.  I've found the tree-grid component, Now i just have to have the columns work with multiple field Names.  Can any one please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Is the related column name mandatory?  because you can achieve this with `lightning:treeGrid` without columns

Comment: Yes, related Column name is mandatory.

Comment: you can try creating a tree grid from scratch:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/ and merge with tree https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/#site-main-content as there is no standard component which can achieve this

Comment: I created the tree grid but how do I merge the trees. Please help me on this

Comment: Instead of merging tree I believe you could also use component hierarchy for the desired effect. This will also simplify further manipulations later. Is there any specific reason for using tree grid?

Comment: @Mitesh No specific reason of using tree grid, the above is the requirement i have to achieve. I tried tree grid for POC.